# The train just arrived at platform six is the delayed 13.15 from Hereford

Tags: writing-style, time

The train just arrived at platform six is the delayed 13.15 from       Hereford.

Q; In the above sentence, I assume "13.15" means hour and minute. But do you think writing hour and minute like this is right?

Comment: No opinion necessary. [24 hour clock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) is definitely acceptable, especially where a service runs 24 hours and character count on digital signs is a factor.

Comment: **1** "British Rail and London Transport switched to the 24-hour clock for timetables in 1964" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#History)  **2** "The traditional representation with a dot remains in widespread use" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe)

Comment: Asking for opinion makes a post off topic. I have edited out that part of the question.

Comment: Maybe OP is concerned about the `.` instead of a `?`. To OP: yes, that’s fine too. The whole sentence is fine. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: The same could be used in North America. Trains are referred to by their arrival times. In speaking (not sure about in writing), we would say: the one fifteen from [town]. Not sure how that would be written in AmE.

Answer (score 2):

That is how trains are described by railway staff in the UK when making announcements. In the past, the 12-hour clock was used. Such a construction is perfectly normal. A train is identified to the public as the "hour [dot/period] minutes" train from [starting station].

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question is over how to write and punctuate the time, Cambridge dictionaries say either a full stop or colon can be used: [Punctuation, from English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/punctuation). [The Guardian style guide](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-t) recommends full stops with 24 hour times (this does not mean other forms are wrong, only that it wants its journalists to use them). Both sources state that "13.15" is correct.